# Sum up columns tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to add a varchar which looks like a number to another varchar which looks like a date

varchar **A** looks like this: 5

varchar **B** looks like this: 1999.08.22

What I want to do is add varchar **A** to varchar **B** so that it looks like this: 2004.08.22 and save it in a new column called **C**

```
UPDATE D061_15018659.dbo.T_OBJ2001 
SET C  = A + B
```

This add does not do a sum up and just adds it to the end.

Comment: You say that varchar B looks like a date. Is it really always a valid date? The answers using cast or convert assume that it is, but if it ever is not, then you will get errors using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you should really do is read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) and refactor your database instead of keeping varchar values for ints and dates.

Assuming you can't change the database structure, you can probably convert `B` to `date` and use `dateadd` (Note I've had to replace the dots with empty strings in order to do the actual convert):

```
UPDATE D061_15018659.dbo.T_OBJ2001 
SET C = DATEADD(YEAR, CAST(A as int), CONVERT(Date, REPLACE(B, '.', ''), 112))
```

Comment: I am 100 % agree with you on that one It was not my choice to do it like. its a legacy project that I am working on and it drives me nuts. Anyway thank you so much for your help. but i got this error message:The '122' style is not supported for conversions from nvarchar to date.

Comment: My answer use **112** style (`yyyymmdd`), not 122. Note that 122 style does not exist in [cast and convert documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Function Dateadd :

Like This :-

```
UPDATE D061_15018659.dbo.T_OBJ2001 
SET C  = DATEADD(YYYY,A,CAST(B AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry my sql server is in german so i had to translate this message: The argument datatype nvarchar is invalid for the 2 argument of the dateadd function.

Comment: add a cast as int for column a Like this < DATEADD(YYYY,CAST(A AS INT),CAST(B AS DATE) WHERE ISNUMERIC(A)=1

Comment: UPDATE D061_15018659.dbo.T_OBJ2001 
SET C  = DATEADD(YYYY,CAST(A AS INT),CAST(B AS DATE) WHERE ISNUMERIC(A)=1